# Formview cannot show data from gridview's selected index

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, formview

I am trying to implement a function:
 when you click on edit, you will load the item in the formview (which should then be put into edit mode.

But the problem is that the formview always show the first row of the grid on edit mode.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? Thank you.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div style="overflow-x:scroll; overflow-y:hidden; width:auto; height:auto">
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="CustomerID,ModifyBy" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_gridView" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="325px" HorizontalAlign="Center" Width="809px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerID" HeaderText="CustomerID" SortExpression="CustomerID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerName" HeaderText="CustomerName" SortExpression="CustomerName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CustomerTitle" HeaderText="CustomerTitle" SortExpression="CustomerTitle" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address1" HeaderText="Address1" SortExpression="Address1" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" SortExpression="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="StateID" HeaderText="StateID" SortExpression="StateID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CountryID" HeaderText="CountryID" SortExpression="CountryID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="PostalCode" HeaderText="PostalCode" SortExpression="PostalCode" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Email" HeaderText="Email" SortExpression="Email" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ModifyBy" HeaderText="ModifyBy" SortExpression="ModifyBy" />
        <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="IsActive" HeaderText="IsActive" SortExpression="IsActive" ReadOnly="true" />
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#990000" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#FFFBD6" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#FFCC66" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Navy" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#FDF5AC" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4D0000" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#FCF6C0" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#820000" />
</asp:GridView>
</div>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_gridView" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SummerBreezeConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT CustomerName, CustomerTitle, Address1, City, StateID, CountryID, PostalCode, Email, CustomerID, ModifyBy, IsActive FROM Customer" UpdateCommand="adn_Customer_UPDATE" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" DeleteCommand="adn_Customer_DELETE" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" InsertCommand="adn_Customer_INSERT" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ModifyBy" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerTitle" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Address1" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="StateID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PostalCode" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CountryID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CreateBy" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Direction="InputOutput" Name="CustomerID" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerTitle" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Address1" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="StateID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PostalCode" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CountryID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ModifyBy" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#DEDFDE" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="CustomerID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_formView" ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Vertical" Height="237px" OnItemUpdated="FormView1_ItemUpdated" Width="342px">
    <EditItemTemplate>
        CustomerName:
        <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CustomerName") %>' />
        <br />
        CustomerTitle:
        <asp:TextBox ID="CustomerTitleTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CustomerTitle") %>' />
        <br />
        Address1:
        <asp:TextBox ID="Address1TextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Address1") %>' />
        <br />
        City:
        <asp:TextBox ID="CityTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("City") %>' />
        <br />
        StateID:
        <asp:TextBox ID="StateIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StateID") %>' />
        <br />
        CountryID:
        <asp:TextBox ID="CountryIDTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CountryID") %>' />
        <br />
        PostalCode:
        <asp:TextBox ID="PostalCodeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PostalCode") %>' />
        <br />
        Email:
        <asp:TextBox ID="EmailTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Email") %>' />
        <br />
        ModifyBy:
        <asp:TextBox ID="ModifyByTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ModifyBy") %>' />
        <br />
        CustomerID:
        <asp:Label ID="CustomerIDLabel1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerID") %>' />
        <br />
        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
    </EditItemTemplate>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#CE5D5A" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#6B696B" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F7DE" />
</asp:FormView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource_formView" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:SummerBreezeConnectionString %>" DeleteCommand="adn_Customer_DELETE" DeleteCommandType="StoredProcedure" InsertCommand="adn_Customer_INSERT" InsertCommandType="StoredProcedure" SelectCommand="SELECT CustomerName, CustomerTitle, Address1, City, StateID, CountryID, PostalCode, Email, IsActive, ModifyBy, CustomerID FROM Customer" UpdateCommand="adn_Customer_UPDATE" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ModifyBy" Type="String" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerTitle" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Address1" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="StateID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PostalCode" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CountryID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CreateBy" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Direction="InputOutput" Name="CustomerID" Type="Int32" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerName" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CustomerTitle" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Address1" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="City" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="StateID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="PostalCode" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="CountryID" Type="Int32" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="Email" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="ModifyBy" Type="String" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />
```

The code behind

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FormView1.ChangeMode(FormViewMode.Edit);
        FormView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the SelectCommand from datasource of FormView . He does not have the where clause .

You need to specify a clause to filter client data . Try replacing the sql for this

```
SELECT CustomerName, CustomerTitle, Address1, City, StateID, CountryID, PostalCode, 
Email, IsActive, ModifyBy, CustomerID FROM Customer where CostumerID = @CostumerID
```

Enter the parameter used in the SelectCommand , before the closing

```
<SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter Name="CustomerID" Type="Int32"
     ControlID="GridView1" PropertyName="SelectedValue" />
</SelectParameters>
```

Comment: Hi joao, your solution works, Thank you so much. Also, you may want to correct some part of your answer like the PropertyName="SelctedValue", it should be SelectedValue.

Comment: Sorry, did not have Visual Studio to take the test. I wrote the code here in the text editor. So the error. I will correct . If you can , qualify my answer.
Thank U.

Comment: Please, if you can, vote in my answer and mark this question as solved. It helps another users with the same issue and increase my reputation :) Thank's

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I will vote up for you once I have enough reputation!